# Can asteroids contain atmosphere?

Tags: gravity, asteroids, gas

Gas is abundance in the universe, can a massive asteroid draws in these gas forming a thin atmosphere?

Comment: @ our moon may be a good example, although it is much larger than a typical asteroid.  For a small object, gravity dominates?   Asteroid Ceres may have tenuous atmosphere. But why do  Titan with similar gravity have thick atmosphere?  Whether there is thick atmosphere depends on what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a certain size, huge asteroids get classified as dwarf planets. Pluto has an atmosphere 100,000 times thinner than Earth, and Pluto is already one of the two largest dwarf planets known.

Asteroids (like everything) do have gravity, so nearby gas would be drawn to them. But it would take just very tiny distrubances for that gas to drift away, so what little there is would probably be close to undetectable.